# SEO-friendly URLs in CodeIgniter without the use of slugs?

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, seo, codeigniter-2

Is there a way (via routing) in CodeIgniter to change:

`example.com/category/4` to `example.com/category/foo-bar`

where `Foo Bar` is the name of category `4` in the database?

Access from the SEO-friendly URL should be allowed, but access via the integer should cause a 404 error.

This should also work dynamically, where any integer is automatically converted to a URL-safe version of its corresponding category name.

I've seen a few solutions that use 'slugs'... is there a decent alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK a slug is stored in a database somewhere.  `foo-bar` is simply a URL-safe version of `Foo Bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only been working with CodeIgniter for the past couple of months in my spare time, so I'm still learning, but I'll take a shot at this (be gentle):

There is a `url_title()` function in the URL Helper (which will need loaded, of course) that will change `Foo Bar` to `foo-bar`.

```
$name = 'Foo Bar';
$seo_name = url_title($name, TRUE);
// Produces: foo-bar
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

The URL helper strips illegal characters and throws in the hyphens by default (underscores, by parameter) and the `TRUE` parameter will lowercase everything.

To solve your problem, I suppose you could either do a `foreach` statement in your routes.php file or pass the `url_title()` value to the URL, rather than the ID, and modify your code to match the `url_title()` value with its category name in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the link between 4 and "foo-bar" has to be stored in the DB, so you'll have to run some queries. This is usually not done via routing in CI. Also routing just points a URL to a controller and function and has little to do with url rewriting.

Why don't you want to use slugs?

Comment: Because the category names are unique, and adding another table is not necessary.  I figured I could simply determine the URL-safe string on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the search engine friendly route in the database using [this method](http://neillyons.co/articles/database-driven-routes-in-codeigniter/) or [this one](http://neillyons.co/articles/database-driven-routes-in-codeigniter-with-caching/).

I wouldn't recommend throwing a 404. Use the canonical link tag in the instead if your worried about Google indexing both http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html.

But if you really want to I guess you could write a function that is called during the pre_controller hook http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html that checks to see if the URL has an integer as the second segment then call the show_404() method. Perhaps a better solution when writing this function would be to redirect to the SEO friendly version.

Comment: this method and this one both the links are broken.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way (via routing) in CodeIgniter to change:

example.com/category/4 to example.com/category/foo-bar

where Foo Bar is the name of category 4 in the database?

Yes.

Using CI 3,
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Use Callbacks, PHP >= 5.3

```
$route['products/([a-zA-Z]+)/edit/(\d+)'] = function ($product_type, $id)

{

        return 'catalog/product_edit/' . strtolower($product_type) . '/' . $id;
};
```

You can route to call a function to extract the name of the category.

Hope I answered your question and can help more people to like codeigniter as I believe it's speedy and light.

Slugs usage is important to make web application more secure which i think is important.

A better recommendation will be to use route to give you a better solution.

```
$route['(:any)/method/(:num)']  = 'Class/method';
```

or

```
$route['(:any)/method/(:num)']  = 'Class/method/$1';

$route['(:any)/gallery/(:num)']  = 'Class/gallery/$1';

base_url()/business-services/gallery/6 

base_url()/travel/gallery/12
```

[how to modify routes in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216912/how-to-modify-routes-in-codeigniter/30858267#30858267)

Have fun :)