# how to modify routes in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

help me with this.

Take example: I  have this normal url 
"localhost/CI/index.php/base/storeurl".

How can I let Codeigniter know to look for 
"localhost/CI/storeurl".

I have a function named index and it accepts a parameter storeURL in the Base.php class. Help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the documentation at: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally found what I was looking for. Here is how my code looks like in routes.php.

```
/* Custom Routes. */
// Store Normal Pages.
$route['home/(:any)'] = "base/home/$1";
$route['about/(:any)'] = "base/about/$1";
$route['services/(:any)'] = "base/services/$1";
$route['contact/(:any)'] = "base/contact/$1";
$route['feedback/(:any)'] = "base/feedback/$1";

// CategoryPage.
$route['category/(:any)/(:num)'] = "base/category/$1/$2";
// ProductPage.
$route['product/(:any)/(:num)'] = "base/product/$1/$2";


// For Main Home Page.
$route['(:any)'] = "base/home/$1";
```

I really Appreciate everyone who helped me solving this problem. Thank You Guys.

Answer (score 3):

Only three steps are required to remove `index.php` from URL in CodeIgniter in WAMP environment.

1. Create `.htaccess` file in the CodeIgniter's root folder and add the following code:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   ```
2. Change `$config['index_page']` to an empty string in `config.php` in the application folder in the following manner:

   ```php
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   ```
3. Enable Apache's `rewrite_module` in the `httpd.conf` file.

You can also refer to [this article](http://sforsuresh.in/removing-index-php-from-url-of-codeigniter-in-wamp/)

Comment: I just not want to remove the index.php file. but the class name i.e. base (in the above eg.) as well. take another look at those urls which I've said.

can it be modified in routes.php ?

Comment: no you cant do that with codeigniter. You can do it in core PHP with mod_rewrite and htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudo code and a few points in the right direction to get you started.

Firstly, you will need to remove the index.php from your urls. There must be hundreds of questions on here already answering this part of the question, so I will leave this part up to you.

As many have commented, there is no way to achieve this url structure out the box, and it will require quite a lot of code to get working. The way I would implement this particular setup would be to route all requests to a single controller, and handle custom routing within that controller.

To do this add a route to the bottom of the `routes.php` as a catch all. Routes for other controllers (news, events, etc) can then be added above this one. Here is an example routes.php to get you started.

**config/routes.php**

```
// Other routes go up here

// Catch all route 
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/view';

// Home page route 
$route['default_controller'] = "page/index";
```

You could then create a `view` function in `controllers/page.php` that will check the url (using codeigniters url helper), and load the correct view corresponding to that url.

**controllers/page.php**

```
class Page extends CI_Controller {

   public function index()
   {    
      // Do all code for your home page in here
   }

   public function view()
   {        
      // Retrive the url string
      $url = $this->uri->uri_string();

      // Check if the corresponding view file exists
      if (file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$url.'/index.php')){

         // Load the view
         $this->load->view($url.'/index');

      } else {
         show_404();
      } 
   }
}
```

Say for example, a user went to `http://yoursite.com/CI/about-us`, the page controllers view function would take the string `about-us` from the url and set it as the $url variable, and then search your file structure to check if the corresponding view file exists  `/application/views/about-us/index.php`. If it does, it will then load that view file, if it doesn't it will redirect to a 404.

The above is all pseudo code typed from memory, so it probably won't work straight off, but hopefully give you a clue as to how to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Thank YOu Jeemusu. I am currently working on the same Idea you've mentioned here. will share the answer if that works fine. The thoughts you've applied here says exactly what I'm thinking now. I am working on it now.

Comment: Glad it was of some help, can be tricky getting your head around codeigniter when your just getting started.

Comment: I've got the answer Jeemsu bro. I've shared the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I always cant get routing to work.
finally I found the solution. I just want to share to help people in need as I really like codeigniter as it is speedy and light.
I am working on dynamic category title to display on $this->uri->segment(1).

```
$route['(:any)/method/(:any)']  = 'Class/method';    
$route['(:any)/gallery/(:any)'] = 'Class/gallery';    
$route['(:any)/listing/(:any)'] = 'Class/listing';
```

The route will note that as long as $this->uri->segment(2) is the method, it will go to execute the Class's method. Your url will be beautiful:

```
base_url()/business-services/gallery/6 
base_url()/travel/gallery/12
```

i also learned that route have to be specific. if url is like:

base_url()/travel/singapore/listing/1201

Then your route have to be:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/listing/(:num)']  = 'Class/listing';
```

if you have param to pass in method(depend on if you use param or uri_segment),

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/listing/(:num)']  = 'Class/listing/$1';
```

have fun :)